# Trying to rotate an array by k places using modulo

Tags: c++, arrays, rotation

I am trying to rotate a vector of elements in C++. What I mean by that is that I have a `vector<point>` I want the last element to become the first.

Example:

> [1,2,3] become [3,1,2] then [2,3,1]

The number of rotations depend on `int k`.
For that I tried to do the following:

```
void circularArrayRotation(vector<int> a, int k){
        k=k%a.size();                //Minimising number of rotation (jumps)
        int temp= a[a.size()-k];
        int p= 0;

        for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
            swap(temp, a[p]);
            p= (p+k)%a.size();         //Jumping to the desired location in one go
        }
}
```

The following code gives wrong output when it comes to big hidden inputs and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate

Comment: I would love to do that but I need to write the full code myself as I'm a newbie and still learning algorithms and logics.

Comment: *when it comes to big hidden inputs* -- Is that how your school tests your code, where you don't know what input is being used?  Try this -- first write the code for rotation counts that do not exceed the array size.  Make sure that works correctly.  Then it's a matter of just calling that function with the "reduced" number of rotations you calculated using modulo.  The problem is then isolated not in the rotation logic, but in the modulo calculation.  Right now, you don't know where the problem is located, so first thing is to make sure that basic rotations work.

Comment: Sir I made that and it worked but in some cases Time Limit Exceeded. So I tried to optimise that and came up with this.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your basic rotation code, and has nothing to do with the modulo calculation.  A modulo calculation takes no time at all.  In other words, this line: `k=k%a.size();` is irrelevant to the real problem.   And the "time limit exceeded" sounds like you are getting this question from a competitive programming website, and not in a school setting.  If it is from a competitive programming site, how about using the `rotate` function already mentioned.  Then write the modulus code and call the `std::rotate` function with the reduced rotation count.

Comment: Yes, I got my question on CP website (As classes here are still in online mode due to COVID) which I'll have to solve and discuss with my instructor in next session and ty I'll go through my initial code again.

Comment: What test cases have you tried?

Comment: If you are going to create a new `vector`, I suggest to take the original by const &, and fill a new one on the go.

Comment: And it is pretty easy to make some bad outputs. Try passing in `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and `k = 2`.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep yes, ty sir. Solved!